# Eletric field inside of a conductive charged spherical shell, which has an inner conductive sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Suppose a charged spherical shell, centered at the origin, with outer radius of $R_0$ and inner radius of $R_i$, and it has charge $Q$. Inside the shell, there is a conductive sphere with charge $q$ and radius $r \lt R_i$. This smaller sphere isn't centered at the origin, it is displaced by a value $d$ such that $d+r \lt R_i$. How could I find the electric  field inside the shell and outside the sphere in this situation?

Comment: You need to use the method of images. If not you have to solve Laplace's equation.

Answer (score 0):

The inner charge (q) would attract a similar charge (-q) to the inner surface of the outer sphere, but the lack of symmetry would make finding the resulting field a challenge.